# How to forward user's message on authentication

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using Bot Framework, and AzureAuthDialog to authenticate the user.

The bot first asks the user what he wants. Whenever the user writes a message we check whether he is authenticated or not. If we find he is not authenticated, we would like to ask him to authenticate. Once he completes authentication I would like to continue processing his request from before the authentication.

On the other hand, what currently happens is that after the user authenticates, we lose the users message. Here's the code, see the comments inline to understand more:

```
public class IntentHandler : LuisDialog<object>
    {
protected override async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
        {
            if (!await context.IsUserAuthenticated(m_resourceId))
            {
// this has the user's message
                var message = await item;
// The next thing that is called here is ResumeAfterAuth function, but it does not have the user's message anymore
                await context.Forward(new AzureAuthDialog(m_resourceId), ResumeAfterAuth, message, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            else
            {
                await base.MessageReceived(context, item);
            }
        }

        private async Task ResumeAfterAuth(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> item)
        {
// this does not have the users's message, it only includes "User is loged in"
                var message = await item;
                await context.PostAsync(message);
                PrivateTracer.Tracer.TraceInformation($"User {context.GetUserMail()} signed in");
                await context.PostAsync(c_welcomeQuestion);
            }
    }
```

Any idea how to pass the users message from before the authentication?
I know I can save the user's message in a field on MessageReceived `enter code here`but that seems too ugly. Is there another way?

Comment: Is AzureAuthDialog from AuthBot or is custom one created by you?

Comment: It's from auth bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *IAwaitable* in your *ResumeAfterAuth* method is the result of the dialog that you called (*AzureAuthDialog*), not the initial user's message.

If you don't own the *AzureAuthDialog*, you need to keep the original message around yourself and pass it to your callback (*ResumeAfterAuth*). You could keep it as a member variable of your dialog class or through clousure on a lambda function, something like this:

```
if (!await context.IsUserAuthenticated(m_resourceId))
{    
     var initialUserText = (await item).Text;
     await context.Forward(new AzureAuthDialog(m_resourceId), (_context, _item) => ResumeAfterAuth(_context, _item, initialUserText), message, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

And your callback method signature would look like this:

```
private async Task ResumeAfterAuth(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> item, string initialUserText)
```

If you own *AzureAuthDialog*, I guess you are better off by having it return to you the original user text when done.

EDIT: you will need to configure the BotFramework to allow it to serialize closures, if you haven't done so, as [described here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/833). You can do it by adding this to your service's start up method:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new ReflectionSurrogateModule());
builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
```

Answer (score 0):

What @andre mentioned is one way to do it, the other best way, is to store the user message in a local variable and then call the base.MessageReceived function after authentication passing the stored user message to it. The code will typically be something like this :

```
class IntentHandler : LuisDialog<object>
{

    private string userToBot;

    protected override async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
    {
        var message = await item;
        //No way to get the message in the LuisIntent methods so saving it here
        userToBot = message.Text.ToLowerInvariant();

        if (message.Type != ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await base.MessageReceived(context, item);

            return;
        }

        if (!await context.IsUserAuthenticated(m_resourceId))
        {
            await context.Forward(new AzureAuthDialog(m_resourceId), ResumeAfterAuth, message, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        else
        {
            await base.MessageReceived(context, item);
        }

    }

     private async Task ResumeAfterAuth(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
     {
        var message = await 
        await context.PostAsync(message);

        Activity activity = (Activity)context.Activity;

        //Store the saved message back to the activity
        activity.Text = userToBot;

        //Reset the saved message
        userToBot = string.Empty;

        //Call the base.MessageReceived to trigger the LUIS intenet
        await base.MessageReceived(context, Awaitable.FromItem(activity));

    }

}
```